# Tikz edge label not sitting at midway

Tags: tikz-pgf

My edge label for `x2 - x1` is not positioned at `midway`, but on `x1` (underneath the `0.5` label). This is my simplified document, highlighting the problem:

```latex
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={30mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle}]

\node[main] (1) {$x_1$}; 
\node[main] (2) [above right of=1] {$x_2$}; 


\draw (2) to [out=180,in=90,looseness=1.0] (1) [dashed] node [midway, fill=white] {0.5};


\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Example image]

---

How do i correctly place the label `0.5` in the middle of the edge `x1 - x2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
%\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto,
node distance = 30mm, 
thick, 
main/.style = {draw, circle},
every edge quotes/.style = {inner sep=2pt, pos=0.44}
                        ]

\node[main]             (1) {$x_1$};
\node[main,
      above right=of 1]  (2) {$x_2$};
\draw[dashed] (1) to [bend left=45, "0.5"] (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Zarko's answer is absolutely fine, and `quotes` library is perfectly accurate for this matter, but if you want to stick to your original code, you have to know that you must place nodes before the ending point of your path when you use the `to` option:

```
\documentclass[tikz,drop,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, positioning}

\tikzset{arrow/.pic={
    \draw[-latex,line width=1pt] (0,0) -- (0.1,0);%
}}%

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration = {%
            markings,%
            mark =%
                between positions 0 and 1 step 5mm % adjust step size here
                with {%
                     {\pic {arrow};},
                      postaction={decorate}}%
            }%
        ]%
        \path[decorate] (0, 0) -- (2, 0) node (n1)  [pos=0.5, below = 4 pt , draw, text width=3em, minimum height=2em]   {node 1};%
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance={30mm}, thick, main/.style = {draw, circle}]

\node[main] (1) {$x_1$}; 
\node[main] (2) [above right of=1] {$x_2$}; 


\draw (2) to [out=180,in=90,looseness=1.0] node [midway, above left, fill=white] {0.5} (1) [dashed] ;


\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```